# SQL Developer Identify those customers which purchased two particular products where one product was purchased before the other

Tags: sql, oracle

I would really appreciate some help with a query I'm struggling with.

I have created a number of joins in order to create a table of what products each customer bought on each date. Each transaction is on each row.

I want to find those customers which have both purchased product A and B where product B was purchased after Product A. I would then like the output to show only the Customer IDs that meet this criteria.

So in the example below customer ID jones and blogs should appear on my output because they both purchased product ID A and B where A was purchased first. Lane wont make the list because they have not purchased the stated products or in the correct order. So far I have tried using the where and having clause as well as group by to no avail.

Sample Data

Purchase Table

| customer ID | Product ID | Transaction Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jones | A | 20/06/2022 |
| jones | B | 26/06/2022 |
| lane | C | 15/06/2022 |
| lane | A | 14/06/2022 |
| jones | C | 21/06/2022 |
| blogs | A | 05/06/2022 |
| blogs | B | 21/06/2022 |

Expected output

| customer ID |
| --- |
| jones |
| blogs |

I hope that makes sense!

Comment: Please provide the sample data for both the tables, join key between customers and transaction table and your efforts to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Ankit I have provided an update I hope this now makes it a little easier to understand.

Comment: If users make multiple purchases on products and were to purchase in the order `B A B` would you want that to be matched? They initially purchases `B` before `A` (which would not be a valid match) but then subsequently they have purchased `A` before `B` (which would be a valid match).

Comment: Hi MTO, ideally yes but for my specific purposes this negated by using a max date for each purchase category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct a.CustomerId
from myTable a 
where a.ProductId = 'A' and 
 exists (select * from myTable b 
            where a.CustomerId = b.CustomerId  
              and b.ProductId = 'B' 
              and a.TransactionDate < b.TransactionDate);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for both of your answers. I went with Cetin Basoz' answer only because this query was easier to understand  (my SQL skills are quite basic). Thank you for showing me the exists operator. I also added a max function for purchase date and partitioned by account ID and product code. In my join I also added a date value (over two years). Finally I wrapped it in with statement so I could use it in my main query.

Answer (score 1):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT customer_id
FROM   (SELECT * FROM purchase WHERE product_id IN ('A', 'B'))
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY customer_id
  ORDER     BY transaction_date
  PATTERN ( ^ a+ b )
  DEFINE
    a AS product_id = 'A',
    b AS product_id = 'B'
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE purchase (customer_ID, Product_ID, Transaction_Date) AS
SELECT 'jones', 'A', DATE '2020-06-20' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'jones', 'B', DATE '2020-06-26' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'lane',  'C', DATE '2020-06-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'lane',  'A', DATE '2020-06-14' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'jones', 'C', DATE '2020-06-21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'blogs', 'A', DATE '2020-06-05' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'blogs', 'B', DATE '2020-06-21' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CUSTOMER_ID |
> | --- |
> | blogs |
> | jones |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e00cb97739ae9237e6915f29f0e68b0b)*